# Adding Common Hook to js-mode

Tags: javascript, emacs, indentation

I added the following common-hook to automatically indent when hitting return in js-mode;

```lisp
(add-hook 'js-mode-common-hook '(lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)))
```

Why isn't this working? I use the same exact thing for C, as follows, and it works:

```lisp
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook '(lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `js-mode-hook`.  Languages that have modes based on `cc-mode` can use the common hook for all related languages.  The mode for JavaScript is based on `prog-mode`, so it runs `prog-mode-hook` first, then `js-mode-hook`.

If you look up mode documentation with <kbd>C-h m</kbd>, it will usually tell you what hooks get run.